# Requiring an associated type to be a result builder in Swift

Tags: swift, swift-protocols, associated-types

Is there a way to create a protocol with a result builder as an associated type — for instance, to automatically create an initializer that takes a result builder closure?

Right now, I'm trying to do something like this:

```swift
public protocol ResultBuildable {
    @resultBuilder associatedtype Builder
    
    init(@Builder builder: () -> Self)
}
```

But the compiler doesn't like it very much:

```
'@resultBuilder' attribute cannot be applied to this declaration
```

(There's also `Unknown attribute 'Builder'`, but that's dependent on the previous error.)